# How to use function typedef in C/C++ source?

Tags: c++, c, typedef

I'm building a piece of code that is intended to be used by many projects. Both in C and C++. (The #ifdef __cplusplus stuff has been taken care of).

The project makes use of callbacks and pointers to functions. Too make things easy I would like to use typedefs of functions. For example

Header:

```
typedef void(MyFunctionTypedef)(unsigned char* data, int len);

MyFunctionTypedef ProcessData;
```

Source:

```
MyFunctionTypedef ProcessData
{
  ...
}
```

This works fine in Borland CBuilder.

But I also tried it in Arduino and there I get an error in the source code
`error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token`

Is there a way to make this work in every C or C++ compiler?

Comment: You shouldn't do this, even if your comiler allows it (and he shouldn't because it's non standard). If you declare `ProcessData` like this, you have no idea about the function parameters, you need to look them up in the typedef.

Comment: Borland C builder seems not to be a C compiler then. The C standard explicitly says that using a typedef in function definition is forbidden, period.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot define a function with a typedef, ever. Borland C++Builder probably has a compiler extension that allows you to do so, but there is nothing standard-compliant you can do.

Comment: Nonsense. Function typedefs have always been possible in C and C++ both. You just can't declare an _instance_ of the typedef but that's another story.

Comment: @Lundin you're right, but that's not what I've written. One can declare a function with a typedef just fine, but not define it, and that's what OP is trying to do.

Comment: It's worth calling out that what the OP probably wants is a _forward declaration_ and not a `typedef` per se.

Comment: @Mgetz no, that part is good: `ProcessData` is correctly declared using the typedef.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use typedefs for declaring functions. Only use them when declaring function pointers:

```
typedef void(MyFunctionTypedef)(unsigned char* data, int len);

void ProcessData (unsigned char* data, int len);
{
  ...
}

MyFunctionTypedef* ptr = ProcessData; // function pointer

ptr(); // call function
```

If you are looking for a function template to re-use for function definitions, there's not really such a thing.